# ASP.NET Core 2.1 integration testing with Windows authentication and Active Directory

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, active-directory, integration-testing

After years of TBH not bothering doing any integration testing with my apps I've decided to jump in and give it a go.

So now I'm trying to get integration testing with my .NET Core 2.1 application, the app works fine when debugging normally through Visual Studio or when its been deployed to our IIS server, but when I run an integration test in Visual Studio to test a controller I just get the following error:-

**No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found**

I'm using the Authorize attribute and Active Directory groups in the roles. If I remove the [Authoize(Roles = "MYDOMAIN\SomeGroup")] from the controller the integration tests work fine!?!

At first I thought it was because I'd not done 'AddAuthentication' in the ConfigureServices method and 'UseAuthentication' in Configure method but this seems to make no difference.

Here's my test code:

```
public class TestMyController : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public TestMyController(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();
    }        

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("api/somecontroller/someaction")]
    public async Task TestSomeControllerSomeAction(string url)
    {            
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseBody = await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
                
        Assert.NotEmpty(responseBody);
    }
}
```

So again, this test code works, but only if I remove the [Authorize] attributes from the controller. I couldn't find anything referring to this in the Microsoft docs I was following and I'm struggling to find anyone who is out there having this particular problem using Active Directory 'roles' in the authorize attribute - maybe I'm doing something wrong or daft :-)

Can anyone help or advise?

Comment: hey @padigan. Were you able to resolve this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @RamiShareef No not yet, I did find a repo on github which may be worth looking into, some of the code there may 'enable' this functionality. See [here](https://github.com/IntelliTect/AspNetCore.TestHost.WindowsAuth)